# VB.Net - Specified Cast is not valid But Debugger showing value

Tags: vb.net, textbox, msgbox

The code i am trying to run is a simple one. get text from a `Textbox` and display that via `MsgBox`. now i probably have done this a million times but i get a strange error. The Code is :

```
 Dim s As String = FromDateTEX.Text.ToString
 MsgBox(s)
```

I get this error from second line :

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'
```

Here is the strange part : Debugger shows value for `s` which is correct. here is the screenshot :
 [image: screenshot]

What am i doing wrong here ?

Edit :

Even this code gets the same error :

```
 MsgBox(“hello”)
```

Comment: The error much more likely occurs on the line _above_ that, since if it was caused by the `s` variable it would've happened already on: `Dim s As String = FromDateTEX.Text.ToString`. The debugger isn't always 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was from the above line. `LookupEdit` 's `EditValue` was in fact a `Short` and it needed a Convert to `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

One line above, you access the property EditValue of control DomainLUE. If LUE stands for LookUpEdit, do you happen to be using a 3rd party component library from a company like DevExpress?

If that is the case, is FromDateTEX a textbox (TextEdit) control from this library too? In that case, FromDateTEX might also expose an EditValue property. Then you might try to convert that value to a string:

```
Dim s As String = FromDateTEX.EditValue?.ToString()
```

I am not sure why the Text property is problematic here. I would expect it to work just fine. Very strange.

Oh, by the way, sometimes Visual Studio goes a little bit berserk. Closing Visual Studio, optionally deleting the .suo file, restarting Visual Studio and reopening the solution might help too...

Comment: Yes both are from DevExpress. But it has nothing to do with third party component. I even tried ‘Msgbox(“hello”)’ and got the same error. I am really running out of ideas.

Comment: Very strange. It smells like a Visual Studio quirk. Have you tried to delete all non-essential files from your projects/solutions, like the projects' bin and obj folders, the the project user files and the solution's .suo file prior to loading the solution in Visual Studio? (You may want to create a backup copy of your solution before you try to do so.) If that does not help, I am out of ideas too...